# composer -v on GIT bash command prompt error

Tags: php, git, laravel, github, composer-php

I am not able to understand why this error is flashing on my GIT command line even if I have installed Composer. I can see the composer version by doing *composer -v* on my default windows command prompt.

Windows command prompt : *Composer version 1.7.3 2018-11-01 10:05:06*

MY GIT bash prompt :

**Mangesh@Ubuntu MINGE44 /c/xampp/mypro (master)$** composer -v

which: no php in (***CONTAINS details of %PATH% variables***)
/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer: line 10: php: command not found

%PATH% has composer or PHP's location already set.

I am also not able to run composer install

Comment: Do you have php installed on your machine?

Comment: yes, %PATH% has composer or PHP's location already set.

Comment: have you closed the prompt and re-opened?

Comment: @Thomas , No, am using same prompt. Should I reopen?

Comment: Yes you should do that

Comment: reopen didnt work, so what i did is, I changed directory using windows command prompt to the MASER branch where my git repository resides and (composer.json) ...an then i ran composer install --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: I did not use GIT command prompt for running Composer